# Proof of accommodation for a Schengen tourist visa (visiting friends)

Tags: proof-of-accommodation, schengen-visas

My friend is in Munich, Germany on a work permit. He will be going to sponsor our stay (residency permit). But our return is from Barcelona, Spain. Will I need to show  proof of accommodation (hotel booking) for our stay in Barcelona while applying for a Schengen visa?

Answer (score 3):

You must understand the nature of "sponsorship" in a Schengen visa. Unless your friend signed a *Verpflichtungserklärung*, he is just providing extra information about *your* travel plans. The visa officials will look for the answers to several questions:

- Do you have coherent travel plans? That includes where you will stay and how you plan to travel between those places.
- How can you afford your travel? Where is the money coming from? If your friend provides accommodation, that explains part of the cost.
- Do you have a reason to return to your home after the visa? A stable, well-paid job is best, but there are other options.

So if you are planning to stay in Barcelona for one or more nights, you should explain where in Barcelona you are staying. A hotel booking is one option, and probably the best if you plan to stay in a hotel.